# calling javascript function on ice:panelConfirmation's cancle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

There is a commandButton on my jsf page, and when user clicks on it, I am showing an ice:panelConfirmation to confirm before sending data to actionListern of that commandButton.

Now, I want to disable this button when user selects cancel on my ice:panelConfirmation.

I think I have to do something to call a JavaScript function when user selects cancel.
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us what your ice:panelConfirmation taglib refers.

Comment: This is it : `<ice:panelConfirmation message="Are you sure you want to update?" acceptLabel="Yes" cancelLabel="No" autoCentre="true" rendered="true"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems bit tricky, or some times it depends on other requirements/necessity.
at last I found [ace:confirmationDialog](http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf;jsessionid=32FB93B716017C5ACBED90F122A8E2B9?grp=aceMenu&exp=confirmationDialogBean) where I could use action listeners on both 'accept' and 'reject' button. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how this taglib works : [ICEfaces Showcase](http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=compatMenu&exp=confirmation). But the generated code is not really nice.

```
<input class="iceCmdBtn" id="j_idt3344:j_idt3347" name="j_idt3344:j_idt3347" onblur="setFocus('');" onclick="new Ice.PanelConfirmation(this,event,'j_idt3344:genConfirm',true,false,false,'/xmlhttp/blank',function(event){iceSubmit(form,this,event);return false;});return false;" onfocus="setFocus(this.id);" type="submit" value="Generate a Random Number">
```

It seems to be hard to handle event on these generated components, because of generated ids. I will recommend you to use [Jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation). It is very easy to use and very powerfull.